# React: passing state value as parameter to method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I want to make my class more reusable. I have huge form to handle, and I don't want write single method for each input. How to pass state value as parameter to method?

I was trying:

```
  state = {
    subtitle: ""
  };


  inputHandler = (e, param) => this.setState({ [param]: e.target.value });

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.title}
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.subtitle}
          onChange={e => this.inputHandler(this.state.subtitle)}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
```

and different similar combinations of this solution.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/kw6pnxwv0v

Comment: class or stateless component, you can define dump(stateless) component and then reuse your custom component using props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    subtitle: ""
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

     this.setState({
       [name]: value
     });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.title}
        <input
          type="text"
          name="subtitle"
          value={this.state.subtitle}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        {this.state.subtitle}
      </>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Let me know if this helps :)